# ram-charged -- what does that mean?

Tags: meaning

Source: [Assembly Language Step by Step—Programming with Linux, 3rd Edition by Jeff Duntemann (2009)](http://eu.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-0470497025,miniSiteCd-BSG.html)

Example:

> The question that kept gnawing at me was exactly what sort of beast RAX
>   (the computer’s wonderfully appropriate name) actually was. What we had
>   were **ram-charged** typewriters that RAX controlled over phone lines—that
>   much I understood—but what was RAX itself?

Not sure at all what that means.

Comment: Typewriters with RAM (random-access memory), I think.  **charged** = powered by, outfitted with, equipped with.

Comment: The cited usage isn't particularly common, but my guess is it's primarily "justified" by analogy to figurative use of the general-purpose (and *much* more common) ***turbo-charged***. Another quite common related usage today is the somewhat facetious ***X's on steroids*** (except probably not for *typewriters*, since they don't really exist any more, so ***typewriters on steroids*** would probably be understood to be a quirky reference to ***PC's running Word Processing software***).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A case can be made for each theory suggested by TRomano and FumbleFingers, but given the context and the historical period referenced, *ram-charged* is probably an automotive metaphor.

---

A search through Google Books Ngrams shows many instances of computers being *RAM-charged*. This is an extension of *[charge](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/charge_2#charge_2__8)*, in this sense given by Macmillan:

> to put electricity into a piece of electrical equipment such as a battery

That is, the computer is like a typewriter which has been energized or activated with RAM, which in computing refers to *[random-access memory](http://www.pcmag.com/encyclopedia/term/50159/ram)*, the "working memory" a computer uses to perform its calculations.

But I do *not* think this is the meaning the author intended. For one, the story being related is one of the author's ignorance of computers when they were first introduced to him in high school in 1970. He also writes of the primitiveness of the machine I/O in simplistic words, describing *typewriter gadgets* and a *[little golf ball](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:IBM_Selectric_Globe_Wiki.jpg)* and *[green bar paper](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Endlospapier_fan-fold_paper.jpg)*. It would be incongruous to use a technical term, still used in the modern day, to relate such a story. Moreover, this book is a programming book which mentions *RAM* meaning *random-access memory* in many places. *RAM* is almost always printed in all-caps, whereas here it is lowercase, suggesting that *ram* does not mean *RAM*.

What might also have interested a teenaged American boy in 1970— this being the height of the [muscle car](http://www.popularmechanics.com/cars/g790/10-surprising-facts-about-american-muscle-cars/) era— is the *ram charge effect* in an internal combustion engine. To greatly simplify, the idea was that a large, long air intake would cause air to be compressed and forcefully pushed (i.e. [rammed](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/ram_2)) into the engine, in turn leading to more air being fed into the cylinder, in turn boosting power.

The prominent air intakes on cars like this 1969 Dodge Super Bee are supposed to maximize this effect (although on some cars, its main effect was merely to *look* more powerful).

[image: 1969 Dodge Super Bee by Wikimedia user Bull-Doser]

Thus, something that was *ram-charged* was something whose power or speed has been boosted above normal. The computers which the author encountered, to his young mind, seemed like nothing more than fast typewriters.

This term was never especially common (*ram charge effect* does not appear once in Google Ngrams from that era), and nowadays, I would only expect it to be familiar with motorsports enthusiasts. In cars, the *turbocharger* and *supercharger* were more effective and found wider usage, so the average person would probably understand *turbocharged* or *supercharged* better than *ram-charged*. In fact, I suspect many people use those terms without even being aware that they originated in automotive engineering, and refer to different devices.

As FumbleFingers notes, some other colloquial ways to describe something as an artificially boosted version of X are to call it a *turbo X* or *turbocharged X*, or to say it is *X on [steroids](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6566)*.

Comment: Excellent answer - this was my first assumption when I heard "ram-charged" also - thought it was going to be a car question.  BTW - On April Fools Day of 2016, Dodge announced that they would be bringing back the Ramcharged SUV for 2017.  http://trucknewsblog.com/2017-ramcharger-concept-april-fools/